# WAMP running way too slow in local network in Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, wamp

I am using Windows XP 32-bit as a server with four computers on the network; three client computers are using remote server. The performance of the WAMP server has become very slow.

What might be the root cause of this, and how could I fix it? *If the question is not fully clear, please ask.*

Comment: It isn't very clear: What do you mean, it "became" slow? All of a sudden? Over time? What are your system specs? How is your memory/CPU used? Which remote server?

Comment: Agreed, need more details...

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced WAMP as being really slow over the Windows 7 network. We have one dedicated machine running Windows 7 with WAMP and all the other computers (Windows 7) access the websites hosted on on of the machine, but the response time on `http://localhost` is way too slow.

Someone on the internet suggested that IPV6 is the reason and disabling it will work.